# PHP: remove a $_POST key and value completly

Tags: php, html, arrays, post, submit

I'm working on a security feature and I need to find a solution for following task:

I submit within an HTML form several elements and one of these elements is an array named `test[]` via POST.

This submitted array will always contain just one value, in example "apple".

Now I need to check if the array is empty or has the value "-1", and if so:

> **REMOVE the $_POST['test'] array completly like it would have never been submitted.**

Is this possible? I tried working with unset() but it's only removing the value from the array, not the $_POST['test'] array too.

Comment: Why is this an issue?

Comment: Did you tried `unset($_POST['test'])` ?

Comment: This should work perfectly. `unset($arr['test']);`

Comment: I'm performing a (filter)-search with all submitted elements but I get always zero results because I have a database query WHERE test='$_POST['test']' and in case if the POST is empty I need the results where the column is not empty. I know an abstract and complex solution, but looking for a simple one.

Comment: I hope that is pseudo sql or your application is vulnerable to sql injection...

Comment: @PeeHaa Yes I secure the incoming post variables, in my comment I just simplified for better overview and understanding.

Comment: @akDeveloper this was _years ago_, but your **are** correct. `unset` will completely _erase_ the variable-- in this case, a `$_POST`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works fine for me. You must be doing it wrong.

```
<?php
$arr = array('test' => array('apple'));
var_dump($arr);
unset($arr['test']);
var_dump($arr);
```

...

```
array(1) {
  ["test"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "apple"
  }
}
array(0) {
}
```

Comment: thank you, I used `empty()` in my if condition, now using `in_array()` for checking if it is empty and the `unset()` works.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution, is to remove the input on the form that has the name of `name="test"` Eg:

```
<form method="post">
 <input type="text" name="test" value="apple"> <br>
 <input type="text" name="Another"><br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form">
</form>
```

The form will be as followed:

> array (  "test" => "apple",  "Another" => "" )

Just remove the input from the form and add a variable placeholder for the constant value.